# Exclude sections from bookmarks or get sections with no numbers

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks

Really the question is on Title. I'm creating a book, it has  parts, sections and subsections. The TOC contains all sections with their numbers, it's ok. But for bookmarks I'd like to get sections with no numbers. Could anybody show the suitable option(s) for `hyperref` or `bookmark` packages to get this result?

Comment: The usual way is to provide a MWE here, not forcing users to glue an example for you. There is no `hyperref` package option that prevents bookmarks for some level, however, there's another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerical value of `toclevel@foo` commands decide whether a section level is shown in the `bookmarks` or not -- `foo` is a placeholder here for the various structure levels, from `part`... down to `subparagraph`.

The normal values are `-1,0,1,2,3,4,5` from `part` to `subparagraph`, increasing the toc level (actually bookmark level rather) will prevent the relevant levels to be shown. Using values from `100` etc. are pretty safe then.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{bookmark}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{6} % Only for demonstration
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\toclevel@section}{100}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subsection}{101}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subsubsection}{102}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@paragraph}{103}
\renewcommand{\toclevel@subparagraph}{104}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection}

\subsubsection{A subsubsection}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
\subparagraph{A subparagraph}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Very clear, thank you. The first part of my question is answered. Your code makes my parts and chapters visible in bookmarks, sections are disapeared. Could you recommend something to make sections (without their numbers!) still visible in bookmarks? But chapters and parts with their numbers still.

Comment: @OlgaK: You asked for 'or', not 'and' -- you know the difference, since you're a Mathematician (according to your profile) ;-)

Comment: Oh, yes)) actually I want to know them both, or + and. If you dont mind))

Comment: @OlgaK: This is not really easy, actually. I assume, that the `\subsection` etc. shouldn't appear numbered then as well.

Comment: Seems I got something by myself, wait a little. You are right, not easy way, but it exists. I'll post it a bit later

Comment: Ok, I use your part of code to delete sections from bookmarks, then I made manually sections (with no numbers!) like this <pre> \section{Permutations}
\bookmarksetupnext{level=section}
\currentpdfbookmark{Permutations}{sec:permmm}<code> works good. Thank you, Christian!

Comment: @OlgaK: Ok, that's a manual way. I thought you were after an automated way!

Comment: But It exists. And works like in one russian funny story about mathematicians) The automatic way is for future. Thanks!